# Are there any utiltiies to convert a visio flowchart to Java code?

Tags: java, visio

Im looking to streamline a development process, where most data flows are represented as flowcharts (end users are not developers).

Is there any utility out there that can convert a visio flowchart to java code?

Im thinking a simple framework that converts decision points to named functions returning booleans, that link together calls to processes implemented as void functions. The converter will generate skeleton code and I just fill in the gaps in the functional logic (for processes) or predicate logic (for decision points)

Anything?

Answer (score 2):

yes, sort-of. The tools available are a bit more complicated than "a simple utility", and they don't usually start with Visio, though they do use graphical designers and flowchart models.

As one example, [IBM makes a suite of business process management and design tools](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/info/bpm/). 
There are other vendors who do this as well. Not sure if there are open-source alternatives that provide a bonafide graphical "process design experience". I seem to remember some BPM thing built by JBoss on their core J2EE server.  Not sure whether that ever became real.

Outside of Java, Microsoft has BizTalk Server, or at the lower end, WF - Windows Workflow.  The tools for designing workflows (graphically) are included in Visual Studio.